# Is or was -chrome- ever a valid CSS vendor prefix

Tags: css, vendor-prefix

It is listed in CSS3 for Web Designers book but I can find no reference to it in Web searches.

Comment: As far as I know Chrome uses the -webkit- vendor prefix.

Comment: Do you have a link for the book in question?

Comment: Vendor prefixes aren't standard. So there aren't valid and invalid ones.

Comment: It's by Dan Cederholm http://www.abookapart.com/products/css3-for-web-designers. Publication date is 2010 so I am wondering if the prefix was very short lived or if there is an error in the book.

Comment: In the book Dan states that -chrome- is a vendor prefix used by Chrome the browser. This is Circa 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the book publisher, A Book Apart, and they have confirmed that -chrome- was never a recognized vendor prefix and there is in fact an error in the book which they will be correcting for the new version coming out next year.

Answer (score 3):

-chrome- was never a true prefix because chrome uses webkit to power itself so it has the same vendor prefix as all other webkit browsers for example safari. The correct prefix for chrome is:

```
-webkit-
```

Comment: Currently, Chrome uses [Blink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_%28layout_engine%29), not Webkit. It's a fork, though.

Comment: This is true however to target blink you still use the -webkit- prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Vendor prefixes aren't standard. So there aren't valid and invalid ones.

Who knows, there may be some implementation that supports `-chrome-` prefix. But it's not the case of Chrome.

Comment: It depends what you mean by valid. They are not valid CSS according to the W3C but are valid to a specific browser. Obviously I am referring to the later.